# Switch partial view on navigation-menu click

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013

I have a page with a menu in it, the idea is to render the content with a partial view based on the clicked navbar item with also one of these partial views as a default page. Anyone know how i can accomplish this?

```
    @using Opdracht_1.Models;
    @model List<Guestmodel>
    @{
        Layout = "~/Views/_BasicLayout.cshtml";
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>GuestList</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li class="active">
                    <li><a href="">Alle<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Reacties<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Aanmeldingen<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Afmeldingen<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            @Html.Partial("_AllPage")

    </body>
    <script>
    </script>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: Use javascript/jquery to handle the `.click()` event and use ajax to call a controller method that return a partial view and update the DOM

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using Ajax or full page load:

- Ajax way: wrap your partial content zone with a div, and use Ajax
  call to load content on menu click events
- Full page load way: move all page content to a _layout, use this
  _layout in your partials, which are no more partials but full pages, and use links in menu to switch between views.

Example of full page (I would use this):

_yourLayout.cshtml

```
@using Opdracht_1.Models;
@model List<Guestmodel>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>GuestList</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active">
                <li><a href=**@Url.Action("OneAction")**>Alle<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("OtherAction")">Reacties<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="">Aanmeldingen<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="">Afmeldingen<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        @RenderBody()

</body>
<script>
</script>
</html>
```

OneAction.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_yourLayout.cshtml";
}
<div>
    Your partial content here
</doc>
```

Comment: The full page load is actually my back-up idea for when I run out of time, but my assignment would require the menu on the page to be hardcoded and the content to be changeable with a partial view (the menu isnt required on any of the other pages).

Comment: How many partials would you switch whit this same menu? As for your example code I would use this full page, I don't see what do you gain going for Ajax.what do you mean with menu  not required for other pages?

Comment: I have a index page, an RSVP page and an guestlist page. The menu is only wanted on the guestlist page and not on the other ones, so it isnt necessary to put the menu in my layout page. the menu is only used to switch content on the guestlist page (all reactions, all absents, all written reactions and the people that are not absent)

Comment: But my answer is not about putting menu in "the" layout page but a specific layout for this. You can use multiple layouts, and also you can compose them. I didn't refer any other layout in _yourLayout as you include full html structure, but it could refer the master layout in this one

Comment: Also you can move your guestlist set of controllers and views into an Area and set the custom layout as default for that area so you don't need it by view

Answer (score 0):

cshtml page:

Replace `@Html.Partial("_AllPage")`
with

```
<div id="divDetailView"></div>
```

Create Different AJAX call for all Tab click or create common AJAX method if view is common. and call function on click event.

```
function LoadDetailPartialView()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Detail", "Pantry")',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: { Data Which you want to pass to method }
        }).done(function(result) {
            if (result.redirectTo)                  
                    $('#divDetailView').html(result);                 
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, exception) {
            showError(jqXHR);
        });
    }
```

Your Controller must be same as below.

```
 [HttpGet]        
        public ActionResult Detail(int Id)
        {            
            var model = new PantryModel();
            return PartialView(model);
        }
```

When we return Partialview that time it will give you Html of partial view.